# Angular2 boolean md-radio-button not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I need two radio buttons to check between two options. I used following.

```
<md-radio-button [value]=true [(ngModel)]="carSelected" name="carOption">Car</md-radio-button>
<md-radio-button [value]=false [(ngModel)]="carSelected" name="busOption">Bus</md-radio-button>
```

In my component, I have `carSelected` boolean variable

```
public carSelected: boolean = true;
```

But, the radio buttons won't get updated with the value of `carSelected`. Also, when radio buttons are checked, `carSelected` doesn't get updated either.

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: @IsuruAb, I don't get any error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this In Html:

```
<md-radio-group [(ngModel)]="carSelected">
  <md-radio-button [value]=true name="carOption">Car</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button [value]=false name="busOption">Bus</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

In component:
`public carSelected: boolean = true;`

Answer (score 1):

<del>first of all radio buttons required same names to work as radio buttons. everything else is fine in your code.</del>

you should bind `ngModel` to the `<md-radio-group>` tag not to `<md-radio-button>` tag.

and here is the link that shows [how to handle different form controls in angular 2](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deal-with-different-form-controls-in-angular-2)

i hope this will help.

Comment: since this is angular material .we do not need name .check this example.
https://material.angular.io/components/component/radio

Comment: well in that example you can see that `ngModel` is bind to `<md-radio-group>` tag not on `<md-radio-button>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This works for me. There is a method that we can trigger in changes.you can pass the value you need using that.

```
  <md-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="carSelected">
    <md-radio-button [value]=true (change)="getval('car')">Car</md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button [value]=false (change)="getval('Bus')">Bus</md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>
```

My TS File

```
getval(car){
  this.carSelected=true;
  console.log(car)
}
```

read the API reference [here](https://material.angular.io/components/component/radio). you can do lot more with angular material 2.

If you need more features that material haven't .use [this](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/) UI platform.